# check Authentication using svnkit

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I am developing a program that needs to know if the user of this program has access to an SVN repository. The only information available are the files in "AppData/Roaming/Subversion/auth" on the system that this program is running. How can I do this checking using SVNKIT?

Thanks

Edit:

The program can not access user's username/password. The only authentication information is AppData/Roaming/Subversion/auth.

Comment: Did you check out the org.tmatesoft.svn.core.auth package of the docs, and if so, where are you stuck? http://svnkit.com/javadoc/index.html

Comment: I didn't find any way to check authentication without providing username/password. @Nio